# Jest check error instance

Tags: jestjs

I've just started with Jest and there is a stupid check I can't handle, I want to check if something is an Error, I've tried the next sentence but it doesn't work, do you know what I'm doing wrong?

```
//This is the function I want to check
const ReadDir = (path) =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.readdir(path, (err, files) => err ? reject(err) : resolve(files));
    });

//This is the test
it('should return an error', (done) => {
    ReadRid('this is not a dir').catch((err) => {
        expect(err).toBeInstanceOf('Error');
    });
});
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Two things: 1. if you're testing promises you have to *return* a promise; and 2. the `err` you get from a Node callback isn't the same as an `Error`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you answer jonrsharpe, I'll change the code and try to test it again

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working case for this test:

```
//This is the test
describe('testing ReadDir', function () {

  //This is the function I want to check
  const readDir = (path) =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      fs.readdir(path, (err, files) => err ? reject(err) : resolve(files))
    })

  it('should return an error test 2', async () => {
    await expect(readDir('this is not a dir'))
      .rejects
      .toThrowError(new Error('ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir \'C:\\dev\\mph-backend\\this is not a dir\''))
  })
})
```

used latest jest 24, see [async example for more details.](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-async)